# How to order content pages in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I have been building a website using Orchard CMS. I currently have 57 pages. If I want to update a specific page it seems really difficult to find because pages are only sorted by time (recently modified, created or published) and not alphabetically.

Is there any way I can sort alphabetically or easily find a specific page in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the 'Admin Search' feature (available since 1.6).
It will add a 'Search' tab in the Contents page.

Comment: TheTree is another way to explore your contents from the admin, and you can extend it if you want to.